# Referencing class from external project crashes android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I need to share some classes between projects so i moved these to a external project and added the build path and references. Now the android version broke while the desktop version still functions normally. Is there anything I could have missed? All i get from running the android app is a "stopped working" message.

I have found some logcat data. Sorry not very familiar with logcat yet.

```
09-21 12:39:13.778: W/dalvikvm(30243): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418dfda0)
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2437
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243): Process: mg.realmofradiance.android, PID: 30243
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mg.realmofradiance.shared.Network
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243):    at mg.realmofradiance.ChatClient.<init>(ChatClient.java:50)
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243):    at mg.realmofradiance.RealmOfRadiance.create(RealmOfRadiance.java:20)
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
09-21 12:39:13.778: E/AndroidRuntime(30243):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

I am trying to make a client/server lobby with Kryonet and have these packages:

```
mg.realmofradiance (client)
mg.realmofradiance.server (server)
mg.realmofradiance.shared (shared classes)
mg.realmofradiance.shared.Network is currently the only class I need to access to from both client and server.
```

Comment: Did you check your logcat?

Comment: @TCA Not very familiar with logcat yet. Cant find an error, it waits for debug then crashes and logcat is empty.

Comment: @TCA When i just run it, the last message i ge from logcat is "trying to load mg.packagename.android-4/libgdx.so" the referenced package is mg.packagename.shared so is it even getting there?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the build system configured to search the path (so Eclipse knows how to compile your code and look for errors), but are missing the configuration that changes how the APK is built.  I think you need to follow the setup instructions in http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html (under "Referencing a Library Project").  Properties -> Android -> Library + Add.